# R Studio: add column of dataframe to another dataframe (merge)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Best all,

I'm working on a R problem that looks (simplified) as follows:

```
dataframe 1 = Basetable

uid     NBRfriends       x          y

0004        8            5          6

0100        5            7          2

0893        6            10         15
```

...

```
dataframe 2 = modelingdataframe

uid      photo_id  

0004         7857

0004         4658

0004         7288

0100         5875

0100         4459

0893         2566

0893         7222

0893         2858
...
```

(1 userid can have multiple photos)

Now how would like to use a 'merge' statement to become:

```
dataframe 2 = modelingdataframe


uid      photo_id     NBRfriends

0004        7857       8

0004         4658       8

0004         7288       8

0100         5875       5

0100         4459       5

0893         2566       6

0893         7222       6

0893         2858       6
...
```

My idea was:

```
modelingdataframe <- merge (modelingdataframe, basetable$NMBRfriends, by= "uid")
```

but this is giving errors...

Thank you in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `basetable$NMBRfriends`, there is no `uid` column in the second argument, so nothing to merge by. It should probably be something like

```
modelingdataframe <- merge (modelingdataframe, basetable[c("NMBRfriends", "uid")], by= "uid")
```